# i have a one on my chrome icon and i do not know why it's there

Tags: macos, google-chrome, icons

There's a 1 in a blue circle in the lower right corner of my Chrome icon on macOS Catalina.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is the number of downloads that are not complete.

Run Chrome, choose Window-> Downloads from the menu and then you can scroll through and find the ones with an exclamation point. Click either Discard or Keep to decide what to do with the downloads and the indicator will go away.

Answer (score 1):

It also reports the number of things you have not viewed as  indicated [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/3695888?hl=en).

As noted above, it can also reflect uncompleted downloads.